# Google Cloud Compute Engine - unable to use mysqli functions in php files

Tags: php, linux, apache, google-compute-engine

I'm using the Google Cloud Compute Engine and I have uploaded some files for a wesbite. When I try to access a php page on my website that uses

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "pw", "dbname");

?>
```

The browser gives an error saying the page isnt working followed by a `HTTP Error 500`

Any other php is fine, I've tried echo and making random functions, they all work. It's just this mysqli error

Comment: As requested by @xc0d3rz please include `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your PHP script, before the `mysqli` call.  This will produce the diagnostic information in the log file needed to get to an answer for this question.  When you have this information, please include the information in your answer.  (on behalf of @xc0d3rz)

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, turns out you have to install `mysqlnd` separately with the command below

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

After the restart apache with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This got it working for me by running the commands in the google cloud ssh console

Answer (score 0):

your questions details is not enough for detect yours problems,when you got `HTTP Error 500` means an error happened and you need to turn on `error reporting` in PHP.
you can turn on php error reporting by many ways,one of them by include `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
in your PHP script, before the mysqli call. This will produce the diagnostic information in the log file needed to get to an answer for this question. When you have this information, please include the information.

> as @MichaelGaskill said.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Comment: This is actually code to enable logging all errors in the PHP log.  It doesn't do anything to solve the issue.  This is just diagnostic code to diagnose what the issue *might* be.

Comment: It's was misunderstand :(,sorry.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill
but it will tell you where is the problem .. and that's what I Want to KNOW

Comment: @xc0d3rz Yes, of course, but as was pointed out by two other reviewers, as well, this diagnostic code is not suitable as an *answer*, but as a *comment* to request the necessary information to actually be able to answer the question.  Please read [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) to see that your answer fails two of the conditions for deletion.  This is why your answer was up for review in the "low quality" review queue.  I added your suggestion as a comment on the question; once you have a reply on that, you should create a real answer.